# Android OutOfMemoryException taking a picture with camera

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, out-of-memory

I'm trying to take a picture and add an overlay on top of it. Here is my code (only the callback) :

```
 private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {


            if(!dirFile.exists()){
                dirFile.mkdirs();
            }

            try {
                String name = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
                picturePath = new File(dirFile, name);

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(picturePath);
                    Bitmap photo;

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                        Bitmap cadre = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cadre16001200);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(photo);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(cadre, new Matrix(), null);
                        cadre.recycle();

                        photo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       geotag(picturePath.toString());
                        return null;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                        mCamera.startPreview();


                        //Affiche la nouvelle photo
                        picture.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    };

                }.execute();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("PhotoActivity", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } 

        }
    };
```

I get the following error on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (android 4.1.2) , with an OutOfMemoryException

```
07-04 10:01:24.076: E/dalvikvm-heap(2980): Out of memory on a 7680016-byte allocation.
```

Weird thing is that it works perfectly on the Samsung Gio (android 2.2.1) with the same resolution of 1600x1200.

I googled a lot, and I can't use the main solution of downsizing the picture. It is a memory issue, but I don't know how I can reduce the memory usage.

**EDIT** : I found this, seems it was the real matter : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377158/1343969

Comment: is the `copy()` call really necessary? That should just double your memory footprint...

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15380872/876603

Comment: @WarrenFaith Yes, the firstBitmap is immutable, so I can't draw on top of it.

Comment: This is wrong. You create a canvas and you draw on the canvas, not on the bitmap! The content of the canvas is just the same as the bitmap as you create the canvas with the bitmap as parameter...

Comment: @WarrenFaith This is the only way I know to draw on a Bitmap. When I use just after photo.compress(), my modification are saved. Do you know another method ?

Comment: Just remove the `copy()` call. It should still work but reduce the memory footprint...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I did, but Canvas doesn't allow a call with an immutable Bitmap.

Comment: @dors It requires to downsize the picture, so I can't.

Comment: You must use the 7680016-byte version of your image without downsizing it? The crash says your device simply can't handle that

Comment: @dors I just need to save it on the SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply call the empty constructor of `Canvas` and draw the `photo` on it. This would remove the `copy()` call and reduce the memory usage.

```
photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
Bitmap cadre = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cadre16001200);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.drawBitmap(photo, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(cadre, new Matrix(), null);
cadre.recycle();

photo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea, but still not solving the problem. I still have OutOfMemoryException on decodeByteArray.

Comment: then you just see the symptoms and not the source. What are you doing before? Can you try to free memory before taking the picture?

Comment: I only have one button calling the takePicture() method. I have attributes to save my views, camera and camera preview, but nothing else.

Comment: Looks like it was my views that were too big. See my edit post.

Answer (score 1):

you should decode the bitmap before proccessing it to the UI, here's a code example

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```